# A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow results from triggers' is true

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers, ssms

i have a trigger running against a table that does not return a results set:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[LogDelete_Nodes] ON [dbo].[Nodes]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /* Load the saved context info UserGUID */
    DECLARE @SavedUserGUID uniqueidentifier

    SET @SavedUserGUID = (SELECT CAST(context_info as uniqueidentifier)
         FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
         WHERE spid = @@SPID)

   --remaining trigger contents deleted to provide simple example
END;
```

Deleting rows from the `Nodes` table will cause the error:

> Msg 524, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LogDelete_Nodes, Line 10
>   A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow results from triggers' is true.

How do i make a trigger that does not return a resultset not return a resultset?

---

**Note:** The trigger was originally defined to use the non-deprecated syntax for setting a variable:

```
    SELECT @SavedUserGUID = CAST(context_info as uniqueidentifier)
         FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
         WHERE spid = @@SPID
```

and it still gives the same error.

```
SELECT @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (Intel X86)   Nov 24 2008 13:01:59   
Copyright (C) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

---

### Answer to follow

We figured out the problem while i was composing this question. i'm still going to ask the question, since the answer can prove to be *very* helpful to anyone else having this mysterious problem.

### See also

- [disallow results from triggers Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186337.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the problem turned out to be because the SSMS option **Include Actual Execution Plan** was enabled.

SQL Server is (mistakenly) counting the "secret" resultset containing execution plan information as being returned by the trigger.

---

Turn off the option to see the execution plan, and it works. This makes tracing execution plans difficult, since you're not allowed to see execution plans.

This is most likely a bug in SQL Server 2005.